# D3 line chart does not show tool tip and data points properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I designed  line graph using D3.js . Then I set data points and tool tips for it. There was a line drew. But it doesn't show data points and tool tips yet. Can anyone show me where I was wrong? 
Thank you. 
Here is my code....

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>myD3Trial1</title>
<script src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.tipsy.js"></script>     
<link href="tipsy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />       
<style>
.axis path,
.axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
     stroke-width: 2px;
  }

.line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

.tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
  }

.tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }  
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<script>
    
    var xAxisGroup = null,
     dataCirclesGroup = null,
     dataLinesGroup = null; 
    
    var maxDataPointsForDots = 50,
     transitionDuration = 1000; 
    
   var pointRadius = 4; 
      
    var data = [{
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 05:09:04",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:59:06",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:49:04",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-13 14:39:06",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        },{
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:29:03",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
    }];
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.creat_time); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.roundTripTime); });


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.creat_time = parseDate(d.creat_time);
        d.roundTripTime = +d.roundTripTime;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.creat_time; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.roundTripTime;}));

    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

    

    svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", line);
    
   
    // Draw the points
    
 if (!dataCirclesGroup) {
  dataCirclesGroup = svg.append('svg:g');
 }

 var circles = dataCirclesGroup.selectAll('.data-point')
  .data(data);

 circles
  .enter()
   .append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'data-point')
    .style('opacity', 1e-6)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xAxis(d.x) })
    .attr('cy', function() { return yAxis(d.y) })
    .attr('r', function() { return (data.length <= maxDataPointsForDots) ? pointRadius : 0 })
   .transition()
   .duration(transitionDuration)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xAxis(d.x) })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yAxis(d.y) });

 circles
  .transition()
  .duration(transitionDuration)
   .attr('cx', function(d) { return xAxis(d.x) })
   .attr('cy', function(d) { return yAxis(d.y) })
   .attr('r', function() { return (data.length <= maxDataPointsForDots) ? pointRadius : 0 })
   .style('opacity', 1);

 circles
  .exit()
   .transition()
   .duration(transitionDuration)
    // Leave the cx transition off. Allowing the points to fall where they lie is best.
    //.attr('cx', function(d, i) { return xAxis(i) })
    .attr('cy', function() { return y(0) })
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .remove();

      $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
        gravity: 'width', 
        html: true, 
        title: function() {
          var d = this.__data__;
   //var pDate = d.x;
          return d.x; 
        }
      });    

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the scale functions `x` and `y` should be used to position your circles, not the `xAxis` and `yAxis` functions.

Second, you keep using `d.x` and `d.y` but your data does not have `x` and `y` properties (hint, it does have "creat_time" and "roundTripTime" though).

Third, you are very confused about how to handle the `enter` and `update` pattern.  On `enter` just do the append.  On `update` do the positioning.

Forth, only put the things you wish to transition after the `.transition()` call (ie the opacity).

Putting all the advice together:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>myD3Trial1</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jaz303/tipsy/master/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>     
<link href="https://rawgit.com/jaz303/tipsy/master/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />       
<style>
.axis path,
.axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
     stroke-width: 2px;
  }

.line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

.tick text{
    font-size: 16px;
  }

.tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }  
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<script>
    
    var xAxisGroup = null,
     dataCirclesGroup = null,
     dataLinesGroup = null; 
    
    var maxDataPointsForDots = 50,
     transitionDuration = 1000; 
    
   var pointRadius = 4; 
      
    var data = [{
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 05:09:04",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:59:06",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:49:04",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        }, {
            "creat_time": "2013-03-13 14:39:06",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
        },{
            "creat_time": "2013-03-12 14:29:03",
            "record_status": "ok",
            "roundTripTime": "0"
    }];
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.creat_time); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.roundTripTime); });


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.creat_time = parseDate(d.creat_time);
        d.roundTripTime = +d.roundTripTime;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.creat_time; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.roundTripTime;}));

    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

    

    svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", line);
    
   
    // Draw the points
    
 if (!dataCirclesGroup) {
  dataCirclesGroup = svg.append('svg:g');
 }

 var circles = dataCirclesGroup.selectAll('.data-point')
  .data(data);

 circles
  .enter()
   .append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'data-point')
    .style('opacity', 1e-6);

 circles
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.creat_time) })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.roundTripTime) })
  .attr('r', function() { return (data.length <= maxDataPointsForDots) ? pointRadius : 0 })
  .transition()
  .duration(transitionDuration)
  .style('opacity', 1);

 circles
  .exit()
   .transition()
   .duration(transitionDuration)
    // Leave the cx transition off. Allowing the points to fall where they lie is best.
    //.attr('cx', function(d, i) { return xAxis(i) })
    .attr('cy', function() { return y(0) })
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .remove();

      $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
        gravity: 'width', 
        html: true, 
        title: function() {
          console.log(this.__data__);
          var d = this.__data__;
   //var pDate = d.x;
          return d.creat_time.toLocaleDateString(); 
        }
      });

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```